# Error I'm getting with React: If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications, spotify

So what I'm trying to do is get all the playlists from a user, which is working as I can see it when I console.log it. But I'm getting an error regarding to use an array to render the collection of children, for the playlist variable in getAll because that's where I'm trying to store it. I'm very new to react and javascript so I'm sure it's a bonehead error.

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    var list = new Array();
    const params = this.getHashParams(); //tokens saved here
    const token = params.access_token;
    if (token) {
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);
    }
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: token ? true : false,
      nowPlaying: { name: ' Not Checked', albumArt: '', albumName: ' Nobody'},
      getAll: {playlists: []}
    };
    this.getNowPlaying = this.getNowPlaying.bind(this);
    this.getPlaylists = this.getPlaylists.bind(this);
  }

  getHashParams() { //uses authenticated users refresh and access token
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    e = r.exec(q)
    while (e) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
       e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  getNowPlaying(){
        spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
          .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
              nowPlaying: { 
                  name: response.item.name, 
                  albumArt: response.item.album.images[0].url,
                  albumName: response.item.album.name
                }
            });
          }) 
    }


  getPlaylists(){
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.items)
        this.setState({
          getAll: { 
            playlists: response.items
           }
        });
      })  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <a href='http://localhost:8888' > 
                <button> Logout </button> 
            </a>
            <div>
                Now Playing: 
                { this.state.nowPlaying.name }
            </div>
            <div>
                Album: 
                { this.state.nowPlaying.albumName }
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src={this.state.nowPlaying.albumArt} style={{ height: 150 }} />
            </div>
           <ul>
            {           
                this.state.getAll.map((playlist, index) => (
                <li key={index}> { playlist }</li>
                ))
            }
            </ul>
            {
                <button onClick={() => this.getPlaylists()}>
                    Check Playlists
                </button>
            }

            { 
                this.state.loggedIn &&
                <button onClick={() => this.getNowPlaying()}>
                    Check Now Playing
                </button> 
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React won't work that way. You can do like this

```
render() {
 return (
   <>
     All playlists:
   <ul>
     {
        this.state.getAll.playlist.map((playlist, index) => (
          <li key={index}> { playlist }</li>
        ))
     }
   </ul>
    <button onClick={() => this.getPlaylists()}>
         Check Playlists
     </button>
 </>
 )
}
```

Also, you need to bind all your functions in constructor or use arrow functions.

`this.getNowPlaying = this.getNowPlaying.bind(this);`

Comment: have you inserted above snippet in class component?

Comment: yes, 'this.state...' worked when I was retrieving other info like this.state.nowPlaying.name and other features in the lines above and below. It is also a parsing error that i'm getting with it, not sure if that helps.

Comment: could you please edit your question with updated code?

Comment: Annoyingly, now on the line where it has, "this.state.getAll.map..." there's an error of "Unexpected token, expected '}'". I edited the original code again to have it match your prior fix. When i remove that block within the <ul> tag, the code will compile. So the bracket issue is solely persisting in that code block

Comment: As per state structure it must `this.state.getAll.playlist`. See my edit with added paranthesis

Comment: nevermind, I fixed it, since it was objects in the array I just had to get a property (playlist.name) of that object

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace...

```
{this.state.getAll.playlists}
```

with...

```
{this.state.getAll.playlists.map(playlist => <div>{playlist}</div>)}
```

I think right now you are not really iterating over the array of playlists.